# I am having some trouble with the microphone. It just kept high. Very loud noises are recorded

Tags: 22.04, microphone

I am facing serious issues in meetings. I am having some trouble with the microphone. It just kept high. Very loud noises are recorded. Whether I connect with headphones or without headphones the noise remains.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How are your level's set in the alsamixer?

If you still have problems you may need to look at [noise cancellation](https://www.informaticar.net/enable-noise-cancellation-in-ubuntu/) by editing the /etc/pulse/default.pa file to include/enable this feature.

Comment: how to check level please?

Comment: i have changed the db to -20db the noise still remains.

Comment: If you cannot open the GUI you can open it via terminal and use the command alsamixer then F6 to choose your sound card, then F4 for capture, then arrows to increase or decrease, et cetera

Comment: Also, your speakers and mic aren't close together are they?  Do you only have 1 mic?  What software are you recording with?